# Is PostGIS 2 installed?

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis, postgresql-9.1

When I tried theh following command in `psql`:

```
select PostGIS_full_version();
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
LINE 1: select PostGIS_full_version();
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have PostGIS 2 installed, `yum list postgis*`

```
    Installed Packages
    postgis2_91.i686                                   2.0.1-1.rhel6                         @pgdg91
    postgis2_91-devel.i686                             2.0.1-1.rhel6                         @pgdg91
    Available Packages
    postgis.i686                                       1.5.3-1.el6                           epel
    postgis-docs.i686                                  1.5.3-1.el6                           epel
    postgis-jdbc.i686                                  1.5.3-1.el6                           epel
    postgis-utils.i686                                 1.5.3-1.el6                           epel
    postgis2_91-debuginfo.i686                         2.0.1-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
    postgis2_91-docs.i686                              2.0.1-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
    postgis2_91-utils.i686                             2.0.1-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
    postgis91.i686                                     1.5.5-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
    postgis91-debuginfo.i686                           1.5.5-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
    postgis91-docs.i686                                1.5.5-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
    postgis91-utils.i686                               1.5.5-1.rhel6                         pgdg91
```

Why does the command `select PostGIS_full_version();` not work?

---

I tried the above because a script working with PostgreSQL and PostGIS had a problem finding PostGIS. It searches for

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
```

which came from the line

```
pgsqlRunScriptFile(CONST_Path_Postgresql_Postgis.'/postgis.sql');
```

Why is it getting the wrong path, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing the software is just step one. You also have to enable it in the database you want it. For PostGIS 2, in the database you want to do spatial things, run

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

as a super user. Magic should occur.